# Get selected values from multiple select in Angular 7

Tags: angular

I have the following select control which is populated with country names:

```
<select class="form-control m-select2" id="countries-select" multiple="multiple" formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.code">{{ country.name }}</option>
</select>
```

When I try to get the selected values, I'm getting them in this form:

"index: 'value'"

For example:

4: 'US'

How do I get 'US' only without that index value?

Thanks.

Comment: How to get value at now? Could you share your component.ts ?

Comment: controls['country'].value

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find another solution you can always parse the string to extract the value you want:

```
selectedValue.split("'")[1]
```

This should probably be your last resort, though.